# whether or not there exist a non-constant entire function $f(z)$ satisfying the following conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

In each of the case below, determine whether or not there exist a non-constant entire function $f(z)$ satisfying the following conditions.
($1$) $f(0)=e^{i\alpha}$ and $|f(z)|=1/2$ for all $z \in Bdr \Delta$.
($2$) $f(e^{i\alpha})=3$ and $|f(z)|=1$ for all $z$ with $|z|=3$.
($3$) $f(0)=1$ , $f(i)=0$ , and $|f(z)| \le 10$ $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
($4$) $f(0)=1 , f(i)=0$ , and $|f(z)| \le 5$ $ \forall z \in \Delta$.
($5$) $f(z) =0 $ for all $z=n \pi$ , $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

---

My thought:-

($1$)No. by Maximum-modulus Theorem $|f(z)|$ has maximum value at the boundary,Then $1/2$ would be the maximum value but $|f(0)|=1$ which is a contradiction.

($2$)No . by same argument as above.

($3$)No. by liouvilles Theorem $f(z)$ is bounded hence must be constant.

($4$) I think it is true but not sure.

($5$) True. $\sin z$ is the example.

please somebody verify my answers.

Comment: What is $\Delta$?

Comment: $\Delta$ is a unit disk may be.this is question from a book where I can not find what is means to say by $\Delta$ open or closed unit disk.I guess it is open because somewhere author used the symbol $\overline {\Delta}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. Surely you can find an example for (4)? A first degree polynomial should do the job.

Comment: First degree polynomial: $f(z)=az+b$. Now $f(0)=b$, so the requirement $f(0)=1$ implies $b=1$. Therefore $f(z)=az+1$. So $f(i)=ai+1$, and the requirement $f(i)=0$ implies $ai+1=i$, i.e., $a=(i-1)/i=1-1/i=1+i$. So now $f(z)=(1+i)z+1$. It remains to check the inequality. If $|z|<1$ then $|f(z)|=|(1+i)z+1|\le|(1+i)z|+1=|1+i|\cdot|z|+1<|1+i|+1=\sqrt{2}+1<5$ by a wide margin.